# Simply add more space between node and its content

Tags: nodes

Let's say I create a node at a specific coordinate and I want its content to be displayed at 2 cm from it's coordinate. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please edit your question and provide a minimum working example.

Comment: \node[left] at (1.3206,7.8665) {+}; I want that + to be located at 2cm apart from the coordinate (1.3206,7.8665).

Comment: @el_maxx please see the edit to the answer also

Comment: would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz[label distance=2mm]%<---------------------
\node[
  circle,
  fill=gray!45,
  label=above:12,
  label=right:3,
  label=below:6,
  label=left:9  
  ]
  {clock};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz[label distance=2mm]%<---------------------
\node[
  circle,
  fill=gray!45,
  label={[label distance=2cm]above:12},
  label=right:3,
  label=below:6,
  label=left:9  
  ]
  {clock};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Syntax

```
label={[label distance=2cm]angle:label text}]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[left] at (1.3206,7.8665) {original+};
\node[left,  label={[label distance=2cm]0:displaced+}] at (1.3206,7.8665) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```